# How IMAP client can detact Gmail Label rename programmatically

Tags: gmail, imap

I am working on Email client App and using GMAIL IMAP condstore capability for syncing label,read and unread changes.

My application flow looks like below.

1) Initially Selecting the "Gmail/All Mail"
2) Fetching the changes from the server since last sync with last modseq like
   FETCH 1:* (X-GM-LABELS) (CHANGEDSINCE highestmodseq)

Here IMAP server returns the messages for which  label,read and unread changes detected since last sync.

Suppose I have label "A" and it has got 100 emails. Now if Label A is deleted then server returns 100 messages as changes,it works as expected.

But in case if label "A" is renamed to Label  "B" then server should return  100 messages as changes but it won't.

Can you please suggest  how to sync messages which are under Label A previously and got renamed to Label B

PS: According to IMAP server standards uniqueness of a label is identified based on label name and uid validity.

Gmail labels are retrieving  with 'LIST "" "*"'.

Suppose if Label is renamed to some thing else then how to find whether it was  newly created label or the renamed label

Thanks 
Subbi Reddy

Comment: Keep in mind that IMAP Standards talk about folders, not labels.  Labels are a completely gmail specific concept, and their implementation is completely up to them.  GMail attempts to present labels as folders, but the abstraction breaks down in several ways.

Answer (score 3):

> PS: According to IMAP server standards uniqueness of a label is identified based on label name and uid validity.

This is not true. The IMAP protocol does not define a "label". It defines what a "mailbox" is, and that each message has a set of "flags" or "keywords".

When GMail decided to implement IMAP, they made an unfortunate choice to shoehorn their concept of labels on top of the mailboxes instead of reusing the existing flags metadata. (They had some reasons for that, some of them are valid, some of them are not, and that discussion is out-of-scope for stackoverflow.)

> But in case if label "A" is renamed to Label "B" then server should return 100 messages as changes but it won't.

This understanding certainly makes sense. The fact that GMail behaves differently is disappointing from the IMAP client's perspective. I suggest to bring this up to GMail's developers; they do read the ietf-imapext mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that a label rename seems like it *should* result in updates to the MODSEQ of all messages whose label set was affected by the rename.  But it doesn't.  So you're going to have to fetch the list of folders/labels and correlate the old label list with the new one.

As you know, you get the list of Gmail labels by issuing a `LIST` command:

```
A001 LIST "" "*"
```

What happens when the response to this command differs from the previous set of folders that you knew about?  Unfortunately, IMAP doesn't give you a folder identifier that you can use to track an individual folder through renames.  Fortunately, Gmail kinda sorta does.

(NOTE: THIS SOLUTION IS NOT SANCTIONED BY GMAIL, BUT IT APPARENTLY WORKS, SO THERE'S THAT.)

Every IMAP folder has a `UIDVALIDITY` value associated with it.  It's generally there to let you know if somethin has happened on the server such that the UID-to-message mapping you've cached is no longer valid.  According to the IMAP RFC,

```
     3) If the [folder] is deleted and a new [folder] with the
        same name is created at a later date, the server must
        either keep track of unique identifiers from the
        previous instance of the [folder], or it must assign a
        new UIDVALIDITY value to the new instance of the
        [folder].  

     4) The combination of [folder] name, UIDVALIDITY, and UID
        must refer to a single immutable message on that server
        forever.
```

Every folder exposed by Gmail IMAP happens to have a distinct `UIDVALIDITY` value.  When you rename a folder, its `UIDVALIDITY` **does not change**.  So if you notice that the set of folders has changed and you grab the `UIDVALIDITY` for every label-folder in the Gmail store, you can match up folders from your old snapshot and from the current store by finding which ones have matching `UIDVALIDITY` values.

```
# before, label "blurdybloop" had UIDVALIDITY 32

A002 STATUS "mylabel" (UIDVALIDITY)
* STATUS "mylabel" (UIDVALIDITY 32)
A002 OK Success

# this indicates that "blurdybloop" has been renamed to "mylabel"
```

If you want to be extra-careful, you may want to do a `STATUS` on every label folder *even if the folder list hasn't changed* just to catch circular renames like A -> B, C -> A, B -> C (which results in swapping the names of labels A and C).  But that's probably overkill.

Answer (score -2):

No, You can't do this with the IMAP language. Gmail labels are exclusively handled with http(s) API produced by Google.
IMAP has been designed to be used a set of commands send over TCP port 143.

You can check the list of the [available commands.](http://irp.nain-t.net/doku.php/190imap:030_commandes)

Comment: This response is utter nonsense, sorry. "IMAP has been designed to be used by a telnet connection to the server on port 143." is completely and absolutely wrong.

Comment: @JanKundrát : +1 and Corrected.